# [$promise: Promise, $resolved: false]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Quite new to angular.

I am using $resource to get list of appointments from Mongodb. When resource returns i am getting [$promise: Promise, $resolved: false] and hence when i do below.

when dig down the [$promise: Promise, $resolved: false] in console i see all appointments.

I need to do some business rule checks before i present appointments in the angular view.

I tried using .then no change. What does $resolved: false mean ?

Thanks for the help in advance

```
var appointments = Appointments.findByCat({
    catId: $stateParams.catId
  });

  console.log(appointments); //This prints [$promise: Promise, $resolved: false]

   return appointments.length; // is 0 always
```

Comment: If you look closely at the `appointments`, it is an array but the elements are key-value. Try `Object.keys(appointments).length`

Answer (score 4):

> What does $resolved: false mean ?

It means the promise is not resolved. In other words, `Appointments.findByCat` is asynchronous and has not finished retrieving the value. You need to use `then`.

```
function doStuff() {
  return Appointments.findByCat({
    catId: $stateParams.catId
  }).then(function(appointments) {
    console.log(appointments);
    return appointments.length;
  });
}
```

The problem is that the code which calls this must also then be made promise-aware. You can't just use the return value of your function (`doStuff`) directly. You need to use `then` in the caller as well.

```
// Won't work
var count = doStuff();
// Use count

// Will work
doStuff().then(function(count) {
   // Use count
});
```